# ¿hover/survoler/sobrevolar? ¿cuál sería la mejor traducción?

Tags: traducción, informática

Otra vez en el contexto IT, cuando uno pasa el cursor del ratón sobre un elemento de una página web por ejemplo, en inglés se dice "hover" y en francés "survoler".

Existe el verbo "sobrevolar" en castellano que no me parece mal pero sí me resulta pesado al oido.

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: He visto por ejemplo "al deslizar el cursor sobre ..." y "al pasar el cursor sobre ..." e inclusive "al posicionar el cursor sobre ..." Ninguna de ellas me parece tan clara como el inglés "hover"

Comment: la traducción de "survoler" en ingles rinde "fly over", según un traductor en linea.  A mí me parece que "fly over" y "hover" son movimientos muy distintos del ratón.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se suele decir *"Pasar/deslizar el cursor/ratón por la imágen"*, con todas las palabras. Al menos es como yo lo he visto y como menos me chocaría. Y soy profesional de la informática por si eso ayuda algo.

Ejemplo:

> Al pasar el cursor del ratón sobre el icono, aparecerá un texto descriptivo.

Evita el término *"Sobrevolar"* que quiere decir pasar físicamente, posiblemente en avión, por encima de algo. No es lo que quieres en este contexto.

La palabra inglesa *"Hover"* significa *volar sin desplazarse del sitio* no tiene una traducción uno a uno al español. *"Hover"* es lo que hacen los helicópteros, o los colibríes al libar de una flor. *"Levitar"* podría valer en algún caso, pero eso no vale para pájaros o helicópteros. Y mucho menos para el cursor en una pantalla de ordenador.

Si estas traduciendo un programa o un texto técnico, mi recomendación es ir por el camino trillado, usar la jerga del sector y evitar la creatividad. Procura decir las cosas como las dicen otros. Por desgracia, la jerga informática es distinta en España e Hispanoamérica de manera que deberás tener en cuenta a qué mercado va dirigido el texto que estas escribiendo.

Mi consejo es que averigües cómo resuelven el problema en traducciones de programas similares. Las grandes casas de software como Microsoft, Adobe o IBM suelen hacer excelentes traducciones.

Comment: Pues claramente es mi intención, por eso pregunto acá cada cuantos. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: De hecho voy a la página de la MDN pero la versión española es... inexistente!

Answer (score 5):

Como dijo deStrangis creo que la mejor traduccion es `pasar`, pero otras que se me ocurren son:

- `desplazar`
- `colocar`
- `mover`
- `situar`
- `arrastrar`
- `mover`
- `poner`
- `posicionar`

Definitivamente lo que venga después de esa palabra es importante para completar el concepto (`sobre`/`encima`). Ejemplos:

- Elige el menú Archivo y **`desplaza el ratón sobre`** la opción Descargar como.
- **`Coloque el mouse sobre`** cada icono para ver el nombre del programa.
- **`Mueve el cursor sobre`** una imagen para ver el panel de desplazamiento del cursor.
- Para ver un comentario después de insertarlo, **`sitúa el ratón encima`** del indicador.
- Basta con pulsar Mayús mientras **`arrastras el puntero del ratón sobre`** la forma.
- **`Mueva el puntero del mouse sobre`** la ventana.
- El texto que escriba aquí se mostrará en el área del gráfico cuando **`ponga el puntero del ratón sobre`** el área.
- Si **`posiciona el puntero del ratón encima`** de una de las entradas, se mostrará la ruta del documento.

También pueden usarse por su cuenta `sobreponer` (como mencionó gbestard) y `superponer` (como menciono deStrangis)...

Comment: _"Superponer"_, tal como indica @gbestard tambien puede ser adecuada.

Comment: @deStrangis Ciertamente, lo agregaré a la respuesta...

Answer (score 2):

Hay una palabra que define perfectamente la acción de situar el cursor sobre algo: **Apuntar**. Con esta sencilla palabra se entiende que el cursor debe ser movido justo encima de ese algo, y quedarse quieto (algún tiempo) en esa posición.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la palabra que buscas es "sobreponer".

Comment: No. Sobreponer tiene un significado de recuperarse, por ejemplo _"Sobreponerse de la impresión de ver a su hijo en peligro"_. Esa palabra no se asocia con _"poner el ratón encima"_ de algo.

Comment: Según la RAE:sobreponer.

(Del lat. superponĕre).

1. tr. Añadir algo o ponerlo encima de otra cosa.

2. prnl. Dominar los impulsos del ánimo, hacerse superior a las adversidades o a los obstáculos que ofrece un negocio.

3. prnl. Dicho de una persona: Obtener o afectar superioridad respecto de otra.

Comment: el significado es correcto y si el OP (PO?) estuviera escribiendo una novela quizá le podríamos recomendar usar _"Sobreponer"_, pero en una aplicación informática o un texto técnico resulta chocante y contraindicado.

Comment: la etimología de la definición que has puesto, me sugiere la palabra _"Superponer"_, que funciona mucho mejor que _"Sobreponer"_ en este caso.

Answer (score 1):

En CSS que es donde más se usa según la definición de la w3schools de hover es

> The :hover selector is used to select elements when you mouse over them.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Así pues es al pasar el ratón por encima de algo, y el verbo de encima es encimar, si vamos a la RAE

**encimar.**
(De encima).

1. tr. Poner en alto a alguien o algo. U. t. c. intr.
2. tr. Poner a alguien o algo sobre otra persona o cosa. U. t. c. intr.

Además de otras definiciones la segunda cumple.

Comment: En España apenas se usa la palabra _Encimar_, y en contexto de informática, menos aún. Yo no recomendaría decir _Encimar el ratón sobre la imágen_ en un texto técnico. Es la señal de una mala traducción.

Comment: Es cierto lo que comentas, yo no he usado encimar cuando hablo en el trabajo, se suele dice lo que mencionas en tu respuesta. Pero no atribuiría encimar como una mala traducción o incorrecto, lo que sucede es que el adjetivo es mucho más usado que el verbo.
Hay un articulo en el diario [lanacion.com](http://www.lanacion.com.ar/952745-los-secretos-del-google-earth) usando-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el verbo más apropiado es "estacionar".  No lleva el sentido de vuelo, pero si sugiere la falta de movimiento, que es lo esencial de "hover" en este contexto.

En el artículo sobre helicópteros en Wikipedia se describe lo que llaman "vuelo estacionario", o "hovering" en inglés.

Por ejemplo,

> Si se estaciona el cursor sobre el botón, éste cambia de color.

Comment: Pero suena bastante específico para vehículos no

Comment: La palabra "hover" es también específico al helicoptero y al picaflor.  La mayoría de las jergas del IT son palabras prestadas de otras diciplinas.  Lo imporante es que se deje entender y que no suene raro.

Comment: Claro. Pero en este caso, funciona también en castellano? Muchas veces en francés usamos construcciones con figuras de estilo, a menudo con imagenes y comparaciones, pero trasladados a otro idioma en general no funciona. No porque suena feo, pero porque el otro idioma no tiene la costumbre y hacer el juego con las palabras es inhabitual y difícil. Volviendo a nuestro caso, simplemente me estoy preguntando si esta imágen del helicoptero que funciona en inglés, vale para el castellano tb.